# Merge duplicate for various factor and calculate mean

Tags: r, merge, duplicates, plyr

I have a dataset georeferenced with a X, Y profile number and an associated depth:

```
Dataset
X = c(1:10)
Y=c(11:20)
Profile=c(298,298,298,299,299,299,300,300,301,301)
Depth=c(-1,-1,-2,-1,-2,-3,-1,-1,-1,-2)
df=as.data.frame(cbind(X,Y,Profile,Depth))
```

My dataset looks like this:

```
        X  Y Profile Depth
1   1 11     298    -1
2   2 12     298    -1
3   3 13     298    -2
4   4 14     299    -1
5   5 15     299    -2
6   6 16     299    -3
7   7 17     300    -1
8   8 18     300    -1
9   9 19     301    -1
10 10 20     301    -2
```

What I'm trying to do is to merge Depth duplicates inside each profile, calculate the mean of X and Y for the merged duplicate and keep the profile number associated.

I can merge the duplicate by profile using the package plyr:

```
out=ddply(df,.(Profile,Depth),summarize, Depth=unique(Depth))

  Profile Depth
1     298    -2
2     298    -1
3     299    -3
4     299    -2
5     299    -1
6     300    -1
7     301    -2
8     301    -1
```

But I cannot find a way to extract the mean of my X and Y column for the merged depth.
Any hint? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: +1 For such a clearly written first question, and for including a reproducible example! Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add calculations and names for `X` un `Y` values the same way as for `Depth`.

```
 ddply(df,.(Profile,Depth),summarize, X=mean(X),Y=mean(Y), Depth=unique(Depth))
  Profile    X    Y Depth
1     298  3.0 13.0    -2
2     298  1.5 11.5    -1
3     299  6.0 16.0    -3
4     299  5.0 15.0    -2
5     299  4.0 14.0    -1
6     300  7.5 17.5    -1
7     301 10.0 20.0    -2
8     301  9.0 19.0    -1
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate, I was trying to put the calculations as function (x) ....

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` alternative. this will be faster than `ddply`, and it will scale for large data.
It is also less typing!

```
  library(data.table)
  DT <- data.table(df)
  DT[, lapply(.SD, mean) ,by = list(Profile, Depth)]
```

Note

- `.SD` is the subset of the data.table for each  group
- `lapply(.SD, mean)` will calculate the mean for each column in `.SD`
- If you only wanted a subset of the columns, you would pass this to `.SDcols`